# trying to print contents of text box after user clicks search button yet nothing printing tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

User inputs text into a text box clicks search and then the text is printed. Right now being printed in the shell is fine as  I am still developing this. However, with everything I have read in the docs, what I am doing should work. So I am assuming its something small that  I dont see. Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
def save():
   key = entryName.get()
   print(key)

nameField = StringVar()
entryName = Entry(root,textvariable= nameField)
entryName.grid(row=3,column=2)

searchButton = Button(root, text = "Search", command = save())
searchButton.grid(row = 19,column = 2)
```

Comment: You use a textvariable= so it would be nameField.get()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the line -

```
searchButton = Button(root, text = "Search", command = save())
```

You should set the function directly as the value for `command` argument, not call it and set its return value as argument (which is `None` , since the function does not return anything) . Example -

```
searchButton = Button(root, text = "Search", command = save)
```

Comment: yep thats the answer thank you. Its an obvious error  that I should of seen just I had been trying so many different things i got tunnel vision, thank you

Comment: of course man I was just waiting for the timer to expire so I could